# Sonar + JaCoCo - Code coverage for both Java and Groovy

Tags: java, maven, groovy, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm having some problems to make Sonar display code coverage for tests written in both Java and Groovy. I have a Maven multi-module project where a module can be exemplified like this:

```
firstServer
  src/test/groovy
    package1
      GroovyTest1.groovy
      GroovyTest2.groovy
  src/test/java
    package2
      JavaTest1.java
      JavaTest2.java
```

The **pom.xml** for firstServer looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Sonar properties are in the parent **pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>
```

When I run the command **mvn package sonar:sonar** and visit SonarQube to see the results, the code coverage only takes java classes into account. I can't see any groovy classes among my unit tests even though I have many of them. I guess that I'm missing something in my POM files but I don't know what. I have read that it is possible to have a mix of Groovy and Java test classes when using Sonar and JaCoCo. My question is simply, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the sources and tests configuration:

```
<sonar.sources>src/main/java,src/main/groovy</sonar.sources>
<sonar.tests>src/test/java,src/test/groovy</sonar.tests>
```

It seems that the plugin ignores Groovy otherwise.

Comment: I don't have any Groovy classes in **src/main/groovy**. The Groovy tests in **src/test/groovy** tests code in Java classes.

Comment: I forgot the second part of the config... see updated answer. You can remove the sources config if you dont need it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a problem. Since I don't have any groovy sources I've only added the sonar.tests property. 
Building the project is successful but the groovy tests are still not taken care of. I noticed that when Sonar scans Maven modules which include **src/test/groovy**, then the Groovy test classes can't be found. The log message is for example:
[WARNING] Resource not found: myPackage.MyGroovyTest

Any ideas?

Comment: Install the Groovy plugin in Sonar. Login as admin/admin and go to the administration/system/update-center tab

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Groovy plugin in Sonar. Login as admin/admin and go to the administration/system/update-center tab
2. Add the following property in the pom file
   `<sonar.tests>src/test/groovy,src/test/java</sonar.tests>`